# Browser works but ping command doesn't with the router Netis WF2780

Tags: networking, ubuntu, router, ping

A few days ago I bought a new router Netis WF2780. Everything works well in Browser, but if I try to ping a website in the terminal or to connect a remote server (outside of my local network) via SSH or FTP, it fails. Why does it happen? And how to make it work?

The result of my `traceroute` command:

```
$ traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (173.194.113.162), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  0.364 ms  0.408 ms  0.481 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  *^C
```

It looks like the router doesn't allow me to access the server. What am I supposed to change in the router configuration?

Answer (score 3):

How do you configure your router? Do you just run setup wizard type function or configure routing rules manually?

From description you provide it is most likely ICMP traffic blockage which need to be removed for ping/traceroute to work perfectly.

On the other hand, browser works well but ssh/ftp fails indicates more complex problem. Are you sure that your router is not configured to pass ONLY HTTP/HTTPS traffic via proxy somewhere in path? Do configuration of gateway is correct for accessing outside would?